Dropwizard - new entities not commiting
We have a thread that queries external systems by clients. It receives a JSON array containing client information like id (which our system calls "customId"), name, phone, etc. The array is looped and clients are inserted/updated according to changes.
If the client exists in our database (we search by customId and accountId), we check if fields (like name, age, phone) changed, and update the client. If the client doesn't exist, we simply create a new one.
The problem that is happening is that the worker thread creates a new client, then a few loops later, it searches for this client (by customId and accountId) again, but doesn't find it and attempts to insert a new client, resulting in ConstraintViolationException. We don't understand why this is happening, because even with duplicated clients in the JSON array, the worker thread should've been able to find the previously inserted client and update its information accordingly.
Dropwizard version: 1.3.29
MySQL version: 8.0.31
Stacktrace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at br.com.system.db.ClientDao.transaction(ClientDao.java:95)
        at br.com.system.db.ClientDao.insert(ClientDao.java:46)
        at br.com.system.remotesystems.agent.Integration.loadTransactions(Integration.java:1355)
        at br.com.system.core.system.integration.IntegrationJob.run(IntegrationJob.java:44)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2933)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3524)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:637)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:692)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:684)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:679)
        at br.com.system.db.AbstractDao.lambda$insert$7(AbstractDao.java:242)
        at br.com.system.db.AbstractDao.executeCall(AbstractDao.java:126)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1399856-1699' for key 'Client.customId'
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:118)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:175)
        ... 36 more

This is the Client.java entity:
public class Client {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int clientId;

    private String customId; // external system id

    private int accountId;

    private String name;

    ... other fields like phone, birthdate, etc
}

This is the loader thread:
Client client = clientDao.findByAccountIdAndCustomId(accountId, customId);

if (client == null) {
    client = new Client(accountId, customId, name, ...other fields);
    client = clientDao.insert(client);
} else /* client already exists */ {
    boolean update = false;
    if (!name.equals(client.getName())) {
        update = true;
        client.setName(name);
    }
    // ... checks and updates other fields
    if (update)
      clientDao.update(client);
}

This is ClientDao, which extends Dropwizard's AbstractDAO:
public class ClientDao extends AbstractDao<Client> {
    
    public ClientDao(SessionFactory session) {
        super(session);
    }

    public Client insert(Client client) {
        return transaction(() -> {
            currentSession().save(client);
            return client;
        }, true);
    }

    public Client update(Client client) {
        return transaction(() -> {
            currentSession().update(client);
            return client;
        }, true);
    }

    protected <E> E transaction(Callable<E> call, boolean commit) {
        if (ManagedSessionContext.hasBind(sessionFactory)) {
            Session session = currentSession();
            if (session.isOpen()) {
                return call.call();
            }
        }
        try (Session session = sessionFactory.openSession()) {
            ManagedSessionContext.bind(session);
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            E result = call.call();
            if (commit)
                transaction.commit();
            return result;
        } finally {
            ManagedSessionContext.unbind(sessionFactory);
        }
    }

    public Client findByAccountIdAndCustomId(int accountId, String customId) {
        return transaction(() -> {
            
        }, false);
    }

}

This is the create table Client SQL:
CREATE TABLE `Client` (
  `clientId` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customId` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(115) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `accountId` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  # ... other fields
  PRIMARY KEY (`clientId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `customId` (`customId`,`accountId`),
)


We have tried to use Dropwizard's AbstractDAO persist method instead of currentSession().save and currentSession().update methods, but it didn't change anything.

We tried to set Dropwizard's database flags commitOnReturn and autoCommitByDefault (as specified in https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/manual/configuration.html#database), but it didn't work.



Is the worker thread you mentioned in the same transaction of the one that inserted the "client". This is looking like a race condition involving the transactions being used. See this article here about race conditions. You might need to configure the transaction isolation of your application depending on how it is running these threads.

@JorgeCampos the client conciliation is a single-threaded job. The worker thread starts with it's session closed (because it is not from Dropwizard's pool). Then, for every transaction, it opens and closes a hibernate Session. So, for this worker thread, it never really enters the first statement of the "transaction" method that I've posted. On subsequent iterations, it fails to retrieve the previously inserted Client and tries to insert it again, leading to the ConstraintViolationException because of the unique key constraint on customId and accountId.

@JorgeCampos we don't keep the worker thread session open during the whole process because, if something goes wrong, we don't want that the previous operations get rollback.

This behaviour could be caused by the default repeatabke read transaction isolation level. I would try to change the isolation level to read committed and see what happens.

@Shadow thank you for the suggestion. We'll try to set the "defaultTransactionIsolation" param of Dropwizard's configuration to "read-committed" and see it if solves the problem. Do you think that we should enable "autoCommitByDefault" and "commitOnReturn" as well, or just the transaction option should be enough?

@Shadow after setting defaultTransactionIsolation and autoCommitByDefault to true, it seems that the problem has been fixed. Thank you and JorgeCampos for the help!
